# How to refresh listview by hitting back button - Android

Tags: android, listview, refresh

I have a ListView that is dynamic and will constantly change.  The user selects an item and goes to a different activity.

What I want:  *When they hit back button and return to the ListView, I would like to call a certain action to refresh ListView* (in my case an AsyncTask).

I have figured out one way to do this:  By adding my refreshing code in onResume.  But I find it refreshes a little too much -- I only want it to refresh when coming from the forward activities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have figured out one way to do this: By adding my refreshing code in onResume. But I find it refreshes a little too much -- I only want it to refresh when coming from the forward activities.

put your "refresh" code inside of `onStart()` instead of `onResume()`. `onStart()` gets "Called when the activity is becoming visible to the user." - [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Which means that it will happen only at the time that you activity gets put onto the screen.

Comment: Hey thanks, it still refreshes when the screen turns back on which I tried to avoid, but your way seems more optimal then what I was doing.

Comment: Use onRestart() instead of onStart().onRestart() only gets called when you go back to an activity which is already present in backstack.